# Puppeteer Cannot read property getElementById of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to pass a value to the browser created by the puppeteer, but this error appears:

> Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined

```
async function start() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless : false
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo?invisible=true');

    await page.document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML === response.text
    
    await Promise.all([
        page.click('#recaptcha-demo-submit'),
    ]);
}
```

The error is in this line:

```
await page.document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML === response.text
```

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What is that line supposed to do?  What if they are not equal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only use `getElementById` in the page context. Use `page.evaluate`, eg:

```
const html = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML;
});
console.log(html);
```

That'll take the the `innerHTML` of that element, send it back to Puppeteer, and log it in Node.

If you want to pass something *to* the page, you'll have to pass it to `page.evaluate`, eg

```
await page.evaluate((arg) => {
    return document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").value = arg;
}, '123');
```

That'll set the value of the textarea to `123`.